# Django order by via custom method

Tags: django

My custom method is actually a calculation and I am trying to avoid ordering via manager and if possible just use order_by. Is there a way or a one line syntax to achieve this? Here is my model:

```
class Bet(models.Model):


    provider = models.ForeignKey(Provider)
    member = models.ForeignKey(Member)
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game)
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status)
    bet_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    bet_time = models.DateTimeField()
    bet_amount = models.FloatField()
    valid_bet_amount = models.FloatField()
    settlement_amount = models.FloatField()

    def get_profit(self):
        return self.settlement_amount - self.valid_bet_amount
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking to annotate

```
profit = F('settlement_ammount') - F('valid_bet_amount')
my_query.annotate(profit=profit).order_by('profit')
```

See [Using F() with annotations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/expressions/#using-f-with-annotations)

Comment: @DeanChristianArmada - No worries, this also works as a one line but I opted to separate it into a separate variable to avoid scroll bars in the code sample

Comment: Yes, I agree with you!